# HTTP ERROR 500 when accessing PhpMyAdmin on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ssh, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-server

I installed phpmyadmin via ssh but I get the error accessing through url like http://localhost/phpmyadmin. I have upgraded to my php version already installed but the error persists, how can I find a log or what can I search for more information about de error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error 500 says nothing, how I fixed it:

```
sudo find / -type f -name "php.ini"
grep -rnw '/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini' -e 'display_errors'
```

I changed display_errors to 'on' and, in my case, it was because of incompatibility between phpMyAdmin and PHP version, I installed the right one and to continue.